# Would be vs. would have been

Tags: sentence-construction

I came across a multiple choice question in a test, which was as follows:

But for the manager's wife he _____.
(would have been dismissing) (was dismissed) (would be dismissed) (would dismiss)

Obviously, you are meant to pick "would be dismissed". However, I would have used "would have been dismissed" if I wrote the sentence myself. Is it wrong?

Comment: Either one is possible.  It depends on the context.

Comment: Such questions about multiple choice tests are often off-topic. Lack of context makes it worse. Have a look at the [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site. It will help you to ask questions in a way that will attract answers. Welcome to the ELL.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, stangdon! 

Let me put it another way. Can you cite an example where "would be dismissed" would be preferable instead of "would have been dismissed"?

Comment: OK I just answered my own question, at least as far as generic examples go. I used "would be preferable" not "would have been preferable" here. However, in the particular example "But for the manager's wife he would have been dismissed" seems to be the only correct syntax to me. I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: I don't understand why you say _Obviously, you are meant to pick "would be dismissed"._   I agree that _would have been_ seems the most likely choice. _But for the manager's wife_ implies that some past action of hers affected the outcome.

Comment: _Would be dismissed_ would fit if we do not yet know what will happen to him, but think he will probably keep his job (i.e. it's not counterfactual). If we do know that he kept his job, it is counterfactual, and required _would have been dissmissed_.